# Zend Framework API - how to make the application use different database when unit testing?

Tags: php, zend-framework, rest, phpunit

I have an API module in my application which is a RESTful API - basically set of public web services. I want to unit test my web services with PHPUnit. Now the problem...

Normally my app uses "dbname" database. But when unit testing with PHPUnit, I would like it to use "dbname_test" database (which contains the same set of tables, of course).

What is the best way to achieve this? In my PHPUnit test cases I am using Zend_Http_Client to send requests to my API module and then I am asserting the returned responses.

Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I would put a testing section in my application.ini:

```
[production]
...
; Database.
resources.db.adapter = "PDO_MYSQL"
resources.db.params.host = "localhost"
resources.db.params.username = "user"
resources.db.params.password = "pass"
resources.db.params.dbname = "primary"

[testing : production]
resources.db.params.username = "test"
resources.db.params.password = "test"
resources.db.params.dbname = "testing"
```

Set an environment variable in my .htaccess:

```
SetEnv APPLICATION_ENV testing
```

And make sure I load the proper settings:

```
defined('APPLICATION_ENV')
    || define('APPLICATION_ENV', (getenv('APPLICATION_ENV') ? getenv('APPLICATION_ENV') : 'production'));
$application = new Zend_Application(
    APPLICATION_ENV,
    array('config' => array(
        APPLICATION_PATH . '/configs/application.ini',
        APPLICATION_PATH . '/configs/additional.ini',
    ))  
);
```

**Another idea**

[Conditionally set](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.0/mod/mod_setenvif.html) the APPLICATION_ENV variable in .htaccess based on remote IP and user agent. If both do not match, then production is used.

```
SetEnv APPLICATION_ENV production

SetEnvIf       Remote_Addr 55\.55\.55\.555 APPLICATION_ENV=testing
SetEnvIfNoCase User-Agent  !PHPUNIT        APPLICATION_ENV=production
```

Comment: But I want my application environment to stay unchanged. I will want to run the unit tests on the production server once the app is deployed and I will want the app to function normally for users during the time I am doing the unit tests.

Comment: Oh I see. Then I would conditionally load the testing environment based on IP address. Would that satisfy your requirement?

Comment: @RichardKnop I've updated my answer to provide hopefully minimal impact on your production environment. I do not know what User-Agent string PHP_UNIT reports, hopefully you can determine that from server logs or by creating a simple debugging PHP script.

Comment: [Setting environment variables via mod_rewrite](http://www.askapache.com/htaccess/crazy-advanced-mod_rewrite-tutorial.html#Setting_Environment_Variables_RewriteRule) might be an easier solution, since you cannot negate SetEnvIf regexs.